# Interactive objects embedded in excel viewed in share point

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I want to create interactive objects that appear in an excel file viewed via share point. I am told I am not able to use VBA. What alternatives can I use? Please note the viewed via share point part.

Many thanks for any help given

Mrhopko

Answer (score 1):

None. Excel files displayed via SharePoint are rendered as HTML tables, so no VBA possible.

Open the files in Excel to have interactivity, otherwise Excel is not the right technology.